# SQL: Cross table with foreign keys to two different tables

Tags: android, sql, orm, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables:

```
zip_code_data
|zipCodeId| primary key
|zipCode| indexed
|other columns...|

location_data
|locationDataId| primary key
|city| indexed
|other columns...|

x_data
|id| primary key
|zipCodeId| foreign key
|locationDataId| foreign key
```

**My goal is to run a query for either zipcode or city, and get all of the data associated with it from the *zip_code_data* and *location_data* tables**

For example, if a user searches for a zipcode, I want to pull back all of the data associated with that zipcode from both tables.


My first guess is to get the foreign keys first from the cross table (*x_data*, example below) and then use those to get the data from each respective table... Since i'm somewhat of a novice user I don't know the best way to do this.

```
SELECT x_data.zipCodeId, x_data.locationDataId
FROM x_data
INNER JOIN zip_code_data
ON x_data.zipCodeId=zip_code_data.zipCodeId
WHERE zip_code_data.zipCode LIKE '2322%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to post:

```
SELECT zip.*,loc.*
FROM x_data xref
JOIN zip_code_data zip ON zip.zipCodeId=xref.zipCodeID
JOIN location_Data loc ON loc.locationDataID=xRef.locationDataID
WHERE zip.zipCode LIKE '2322%' or loc.city LIKE '%aaa%'
```

but it looks like you've already got it...

Answer (score 2):

You could create an inline view:

```
 select zips.othercolumn, LOCS.city
      from zips
           inner join x_data on zips.zip = x_data_zip and zips.zip like .....

           left join (
                select id, locations.city from locations
                where locations.id = x_data.locationid
           ) as LOCS
```

or just join the locations table:

```
           left join locations as locs on locs.locationid = x_data.locationid
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I actually just figured it out another way right before you posted this.

Comment: SELECT zip_code_data.*, location_data.*
FROM x_data
INNER 
    JOIN zip_code_data
    ON x_data.zipCodeData_Id=zip_code_data.zipCodeId
INNER 
    JOIN location_data
    ON x_data.locationData_Id=location_data.locationDataId
where zip_code_data.zipCode like '23221%'